# In Symfony2, is there a way to pretty-print JSON responses?

Tags: json, symfony

I am writing a REST API in Symfony2, and I have my controller outputting JSON responses using the provided JsonResponse class:

```
$response = new JsonResponse(null, $status);
$response->setData($node['Content']);
return $response;
```

However, for debugging purposes, it would be nice to be able to pretty print the output. Is there an argument I can pass to the JsonResponse object to enable pretty-printing of the output?

Comment: $response->setEncodingOptions($response->getEncodingOptions() | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

Comment: Just a note that this method is only valid since HttpFoundation 2.5+

Comment: Can You check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create EventListener for that. Here is mine

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

/**
 * Preetify json response.
 */
class FormatJsonResponseListener
{
    public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (APPLICATION_ENV === 'development' || APPLICATION_ENV === 'dev' || $request->query->get('pretty_json', false) == true) {
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            $responseData = $event->getResponse()->getContent();
            $response->setContent(Json::indent($responseData));
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

And register that service with:

```
#services.ym
services:
    your.service.listener.format_json:
        class: Your\Vendor\FormatJsonResponseListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onResponse }
```

My JSON class is here: https://github.com/sourcefabric/Newscoop/blob/master/newscoop/library/Newscoop/Gimme/Json.php

Instead `APPLICATION_ENV` you can pass to listener parameter `kernel.debug`.

You can also modify response with (PHP >= 5.4.0, HttpFoundation >= 2.5)

`$response->setEncodingOptions($response->getEncodingOptions() | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Answer (score 8):

Creating an event listener for that, as in Pawel's answer is overengineering.

To prettify, you just pass in the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` constant to the `JsonResponse` via the `setEncodingOptions`, like in this example:

```
$response = new JsonResponse( [ 'your' => 'data' ] );
$response->setEncodingOptions( $response->getEncodingOptions() | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
return $response;
```

You can see the Symfony API for more information:

- Class `JsonResponse`:

  - http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html
- Method `setEncodingOptions`:

  - http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html#method_setEncodingOptions

This is documentation for `v3.2`... but older versions like for example `v2.7` also have this method.